# Which Unix flavour do I need? J2EE application using IBM tools?

Tags: eclipse, unix, jakarta-ee, db2, websphere

I want to try Unix for developing [J2EE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) application. I use the IBM software.

1. [WASCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_Application_Server_Community_Edition) as application server
2. [DB2 Express-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_DB2_Express-C) as database.
3. Eclipse

Which Unix flavour will be most suitable for me?

Comment: I you want to wear only blue clothes (including underwear), then go for AIX on IBM hardware with an IBM JVM, etc. But you know, this doesn't really matter with Java. And by the way, good luck, IBM tools are not known to be the most... friendly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really mean "UNIX" and not "Linux", I would recommend Solaris (Eclipse does run on Solaris, and it's much easier to understand than AIX).

If you mean Linux too, I would recommend a distro designed for servers, like RHEL/Centos, rather than Ubuntu or Fedora.  They are more likely to be stable and scalable.

Comment: Thanx for ur response. Going to give a try to solaris

Answer (score 2):

According to [ibm.com](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasce/): WebSphere Application Server Community Edition runs on AIX, Linux, Solaris, "UNIX" (!!!), and Windows.

According to [ibm.com](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express/download.html): DB2 Express C runs on Windows, Linux, Solaris, and Mac OS X (in beta).

According to [eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/): Eclipse runs on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

The only Unix flavor in common to all of those is Linux.  (If you move beyond Unix, Windows also works.)

Answer (score 1):

Java is platform-independent. **It doesn't really matter** on which platform you develop - you can run your application on any other Java-supporting platform. Hence, you can develop on Windows and deploy on AIX, or develop on Linux and deploy on MacOS, or ...

The Java VM abstracts access to operating system services and resources, as does JDBC abstract the access to the database layer.

Comment: If Rishi were talking about generic Java, I would agree with you.  But Rishi mentioned specific programs.  There may be platform-specific code in these programs.

Comment: The OP's question does not contain any reference to platform-specific code. He is talking about J2EE/JEE

Comment: JDBC abstracts the database layer, but there is difference between, say, SQLite and Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I have a production environment on Centos with DB2 and Apache Geronimo (open source version of WASCE). Works like a charm. The development environment is Eclipse and Apache Geronimo on Windows and the DB2 on Centos.